# vuejs best practice to order table columns by order in array

Tags: vuejs2

I'm taking first steps with vuejs and came across this issue. I have this data i want to display inside a table, using this quite straightforward piece of code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" :class="[hide ? 'thide' : '']">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th v-for="(item, index) in _items[0]">{{fixTheaders(index)}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(item, index) in _items">
            <td v-for="field in item">{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

now the problem is that each `item` stores data in the following form, for example:

```
{ 
  "cost": "123.324", 
  "placement": "placement-1", 
  "date": "2017-03-03", 
  "device": "mobile" 
}
```

so in this case the table will present data in this order :
cost | placement | date | device
but i want the order to be : date | device | cost | placement 
i have a feeling that best way will be to have array :

```
filters = ['date,'device','cost','placement']
```

and use it but i couldn't find a vuejs way to handle it. 
so, any idea what will considered best practice in vuejs to present the data in a table by the order i set in the array?

worth mentioning that when initialized, the order is determined on the server and fixing it from this side is not an option

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just hardcode the headers, and get the correct value in your tbody

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in _items">
        <td>{{item.date}}</td>
        <td>{{item.device}}</td>
        <td>{{item.cost}}</td>
        <td>{{item.placement}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Unless of course you need more stuff done with them, then a property containing the column keys in desired order is what I would go for indeed :-)

Comment: Sorry - just noticed that you're getting the order from the server (why, I wonder, but that's not your question) - in that case, by all means, just add the order in an array.

Better even - if the order is coming from your server, why can't you order the data on the server before sending it to the client?